# Airflow Packaged dags(Zip) not picked by scheduler

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to use [packaged dag](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#packaged-dags) with `Celery Executor`, but scheduler and worker are not picking up the job. I have restarted the `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` but still no success. I have even reset the DB with `airflow resetdb` but still nothing.

I am getting the following messages:-

```
[INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 31418)
[INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32308
```

DAGs are not running manually or even picked by the scheduler.

[image]

My zip file has the following contents:

```
unzip alerting.zip   

creating: airflow_utils/
inflating: airflow_utils/enums.py  
inflating: airflow_utils/psql_alerting_dag.py  
extracting: airflow_utils/__init__.py  
inflating: airflow_utils/hive_alerting_dag.py  
inflating: airflow_utils/alerting_utils.py  
inflating: alerting_12hrs.py       
inflating: alerting_15mins.py      
inflating: alerting_3hrs.py
```

**If I place all these files in dags folder instead of packaging them, airflow scheduler is able to schedule the dags.**

What is that I am doing wrong with packaged dags?

Comment: To verify, when you are trying to get the packaged DAG to work, you are placing it in the `/dags` directory?

Comment: I'm using airflow 2.0.2 and I'm facing this problem. Dags run when placed directly inside `/dag` directory but if zip (packaged dag) is kept, it only runs the first task in the dag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on Airflow 1.8.1 which had problems with loading dags from zips. This issue was fixed in 1.8.3. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1357